# How to retrieve text from all columns of selected row from a GridView within a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to retrieve the text from all columns (of the selected item) of a GridView connected to a ListView. While the data displays correctly, when I use ToString() of the ListView itself to retrieve the contents of the selected row, it returns the namespace and the class name instead of the text from the property. Here's what I've tried so far:

Overriding the ToString() method (will not work for me as my code has multiple properties),

Using `ItemsSource` in the ListView

My code (XAML):

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="ListViewR" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="321"
                     BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"
                     MouseDoubleClick="ListViewR_MouseDoubleClick" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="GridView">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Resolution" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Resolution}" ></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Refresh rate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RefreshRate}"></GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Code-behind (C#):

```cs
// the properties class
public class ResItems
{
     public string Resolution { get; set; }
     public string RefreshRate { get; set; }
}

// method that populates ListBox & GridView
private void ListDisplaySettings() {
            myProgram.DEVMODE vDevMode = new syslib32.DEVMODE();
            int i = 0;
            while (Res.EnumDisplaySettingsA(null!, i, ref vDevMode)) {
                this.ListViewR.Items.Add(new ResItems{Resolution = vDevMode.dmPelsWidth + "x" + vDevMode.dmPelsHeight, RefreshRate = vDevMode.dmDisplayFrequency + " Hz",});
                i++;
            }
        }

// failing method
private void GetResolution() {
            if (this.ListViewR.SelectedItems.Count <= 0) return;
            string s = this.ListViewR.SelectedItem.ToString(); // here's where the unexpected things occur. As you can see, I am trying to parse the contents of the selected row of the GridView/ListView to change the user's screen resolution (with safety of course).
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(s);
            string[] v = s.Split(new[] {"x", "@", "Hz", "bpp",}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            uint q = uint.Parse(v[0]);
            uint b = uint.Parse(v[1]);
            uint z = uint.Parse(v[2]);
            uint f = uint.Parse(v[3]);
            myProgram.CResolution.ChangeRes(q, b, z, f);
            this.HzControl.Value = Res.CRefreshRate;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedItem property has `object` type, but since you know concrete type of those object, make a type-cast abd access property directly:

```
private void GetResolution() 
{
    if (this.ListViewR.SelectedItems.Count <= 0) return;

    var SelectedResItems = (ResItems)this.ListViewR.SelectedItem;
    string s = SelectedResItems.Resolution;

    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(s);
    string[] v = s.Split(new[] {"x", "@", "Hz", "bpp",}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    uint q = uint.Parse(v[0]);
    uint b = uint.Parse(v[1]);
    uint z = uint.Parse(v[2]);
    uint f = uint.Parse(v[3]);
    myProgram.CResolution.ChangeRes(q, b, z, f);
    this.HzControl.Value = Res.CRefreshRate;
}
```